# How can i get the Client Computer name

Tags: c#, remote-desktop, thin-client, terminal-services

I am using C# Framework 4.0 Windows Form. My program is installed on a server TSE. There are 11 light clients that connect to this server.

When one of these clients launches my progam, how can I get his PC name ?

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1768219/1300049

Comment: Is this what you're refering to? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804700/how-to-find-fqdn-of-local-machine-in-c-net

Comment: Are you asking how to get the TERMINAL's name while running your application inside your SERVER? What terminal technology are you using? This isn't what client-server means by the way

Comment: YES, terminal name. this terminal is a light PC, they don't have a CD driver nor hardisk. it just a small box that connect to server TSE. They even not have an Operating System installed

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you are using Terminal Services and Remote Desktop, you can check the CLIENTNAME environment variable to retrieve the client machine's name, although some people report problems with it.

You can get the value with [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6.aspx), eg

```
var clientName=Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CLIENTNAME");
```

For an API based method, check [Preferred way Of getting Client name From Terminal Server Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301079/preferred-way-of-getting-client-name-from-terminal-server-session) which shows how to use WMI or the Terminal Services API to retrieve the client name

**UPDATE**

Hmm, seems the [Cassia](http://code.google.com/p/cassia/) library encapsulates the TS API. You can get the client name with

```
new TerminalServicesManager().CurrentSession.ClientName
```

Another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904660/terminalservicesmanager-currentsession-clientname) shows how to retrieve the current session's client name or the client names of all sessions.

Comment: @Jerther in some cases `CLIENTNAME` returns `Console` as described in this [Microsoft KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971165). I don't remember what else I had found 4 years ago. By now of course Windows XP is no longer supported

Comment: @Jerther also found [this KB article about RDP connections](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2509192) which applies to Windows 7 and 2008 R2.

Answer (score 3):

On the client, use:

```
string machineName = Environment.MachineName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string ComputerName1 = Dns.GetHostName();//Server Name
string ComputerName2 = Environment.MachineName;//Server Name
```

Comment: This does not answer the question as the question asks for the client name and not the server (RD Host)

Comment: Then What would be the answer? @nflash ??

Answer (score -1):

If you are using .NET you can use the code below :

```
Dim PcName As String = Environment.UserName
```

Then just call the `PcName` at anywhere you want to display.

Goodluck :)

Comment: it's about the Citrix Clientname, not the username